# match last integer from behind

Tags: regex

i have those strings

```
hello,world,1.fin
hello,world,start11.fin
hello,world,start11,then,end22.fin
hello,world,111,then,222,then,end333.fin
hello,world,111,then,222,then,end333threes.fin
hello,world,111,then,222,then,end333threes.fin444
```

and i need to match the endings numbers only before the `.` and after `world,` and i expect to get

```
1
11
22
333
333
333
```

i tried this but it does not match the last case `,world,.*?(\d+)\.` [link](https://regex101.com/r/KLyNRw/2) then i tried this but it only get from begin `,world,.*?(\d+).*\.` [link](https://regex101.com/r/zX7lj9/2)

`.fin` is not static and it does change randomly to `.fin444` or `.444`

Comment: What about `,world,(?:.*\D)?(\d+)\.` or `,world,.*\b(\d+)\.`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew last case still unmatched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
,world,(?:.*\D)?(\d+)[^\W\d]*\.
,world,(?:.*\D)?(\d+)[^\d.]*\.
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BpWuIo/1).

*Details*:

- `,world,` - a fixed string
- `(?:.*\D)?` - an optional sequence of any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then a non-digit char
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `[^\W\d]*` (or, `[a-zA-Z_]*` can also be used, or even `[^\d.]*` to match any zero or more chars other than digit and a dot) - zero or more word chars excluding digits
- `\.` - a `.` char.

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
,world,.*?(\d+)[^\d]*\.
```

See https://regex101.com/r/ilIsJb/1

Comment: @Wiktor's answer is more robust to be honest, but leaving my anyways